# ExtJS 5: bind to other class properties, like allowBlank

Tags: javascript, extjs, mvvm, data-binding, extjs5

I'm getting confused on what config values are allowed to be bound, and which ones are not. Currently, allowBlank is not allowed to be bound, as I get an error saying `Ext.mixin.Bindable.applyBind(): Cannot bind allowBlank on Ext.form.field.ComboBox - missing a setAllowBlank method.` If I use a config, I don't get the error, but it doesn't work as expected:

```
xtype: 'combobox',
anchor: '100%',
fieldLabel: 'Affiliation',
name: 'AffiliationId',
displayField: 'Abbreviation',
valueField: 'AffiliationId',
queryMode: 'local',
typeAhead: true,
config: {
  forceSelection: true,
  allowBlank: false
},
bind: {
  store: '{affiliationStore}',
  allowBlank: '{allowBlankAffiliation}',
  forceSelection: '{forceSelectionAffiliation}'
}
```

What I'd like to know is, how can I bind `allowBlank` or any other property to a formula? Is this even possible, or am I totally not understanding something?  And if so, how do I know what I can bind and what I can't bind?

Comment: See also https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?339465-Why-allowBlank-isn-t-bindable with override option.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Only properties with a setter, a set method should be present in the [docs](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.form.field.ComboBox), can be bound. 'setAllowBlank' doesn't exist. `allowBlank` doesn't have a setter out of the box, because it is not placed within the config of the combobox object. As you can see in the source:

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0/5.0.1-apidocs/source/Text.html#Ext-form-field-Text-cfg-allowBlank

By setting a `allowBlank` into a config like you did you are only suppressing the error.

What you can do is extend the ComboBox and create a custom config property. After that you can override the update method (created by the config system) and set `allowBlank` manually.

```
Ext.define('MyComboBox', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.field.ComboBox',

    alias: 'widget.MyComboBox',

    config: {
        requireMe: false
    },

    // override of generated update method
    updateRequireMe: function(value) {
        this.allowBlank = !value;
    }
});
```

Usage:

```
xtype: 'MyComboBox',
valueField: '_id',
displayField: 'name',
queryMode: 'local',
requireMe: '{!allowBlank}',
bind: {
    store: '{people}'
}
```

Comment: Very interesting.  That definitely clears up my confusion on what can and cannot be set.  Thanks!

Comment: Note that the class may not be built in such a way as to cope with the `allowBlank` setting being changed. Many of the uses of it are done during `initComponent` - these settings won't be updated when you change `allowBlank`

Comment: In this way the property is only set once when the view is declared. I tested and the validation is working properly. I'm not sure about changing it later on dynamically though. You could be right. But initial it works fine this way.

Answer (score 3):

Sencha isn't always good at distinguishing between configuration variables and property variables. You sometimes need to [go to the source](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.1/5.1.1-apidocs/source/Text.html#Ext-form-field-Text-cfg-allowBlank).

Configuration variables are defined inside a `config` block. These are the variables that will have getters & setters generated, and that you can bind to. Properties, by contrast, are directly defined in the body of the class.

As you may have guessed, `allowBlank` - defined in the `Ext.form.field.Text` class - is directly defined, and thus is a property, even that it has a `@cfg` documentation marker. As such, it's not directly bindable.

You can make it bindable, though - you simply need to define the right methods. The easiest way to do this would be to create a subclass of Combobox, and add a section like this:

`config: { allowBlank: true }`

and then use that subclass in your form. Note, however, that this may not be sufficient; because the class isn't expecting `allowBlank` to change, it's not wired up to deal with (e.g. changing validators and so forth)

Comment: Doesn't sound as a great idea to me though, creating a config of an existing property. On the same prototype and all. That will get you in trouble one day.

Comment: It shouldn't; if the parent class got changed to include this as a config property, the child class simply won't create the functions itself anymore.

As I note at the end, I'd be more concerned that changing the property might leave the class in an inconsistent state; it's not built to be changed.

Answer (score 2):

You can bind to any property where there is a corresponding "set" method.  For example, there is a setStore() method, so you can bind to "store".  Since there is no setAllowBlank(), you cannot bind to it.

Answer (score 1):

Thread https://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?339465-Why-allowBlank-isn-t-bindable suggested that it's possible to override base field class instead of extending it.

So in my case with extjs 5.1.1.1 the solution is as simple as:

```
Ext.define('AdminKit.form.field.override.Text', {
    override: 'Ext.form.field.Text',

    setAllowBlank: function(value) {
        this.allowBlank = value;
        this.validate();
    }
}
```